# Client disconnects from websocket (closes browser tab) without closing handshake. How to properly handle this?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

I am writing a chat app for the purpose of demonstrating how websockets work. Overall my app works fine, but there's one error message that I can't get my head around.

The WebSocket server was built in ASP.NET Core (without SignalR or any other library); see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The client is quite simple, it runs in the browser.

The client is able to open a connection, send messages and close the connection; this works perfectly. However, if I close the browser tab without closing the WebSocket first, I get an error message in the server:

> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.OperationCanceledException: Aborted  --->
> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (997): The remote party
> closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close
> handshake.

I verified that the same behavior occurs with the sample provided by Microsoft in the link I put above. The official documentation mentions that the server should handle client disconnects in case of lost connectivity, but that doesn't seem to be the case here (it does not provide an example on how to do this anyway). Below you can find the code from MSDN samples, which is yielding the same error I'm facing:

```
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions() 
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
    ReceiveBufferSize = 4 * 1024
};

app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await Echo(context, webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }

});

private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I tried putting a breakpoint in line `await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);` and the process stops there when I close the connection by clicking "Close" button in the client, but it does not stop there when I close the tab and get the error.

**How can I properly handle this in the server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `try..catch` around the call to `await Echo()` to handle the `OperationCanceledException`/`WebSocketException` that `WebSocket.ReceiveAsync()` throws.

Comment: Your suggestion works fine. It seems odd to me that the only way to get around this is using a try...catch; IMO it is a rather trivial situation that should be handled in a more transparent manner. Anyway, it is what it is. I'll wait until the question completes 24 hours and then mark it as accepted, thanks.

Comment: @TC55 what is odd about this? You are performing **async** reads/writes that fail, so that failure has to be reported *somehow*. So an exception is thrown, which `await` handles and re-throws into your code. .NET makes *heavy* use of exceptions to report errors. Actually, you may be able to `catch` the exception inside of `Echo()` itself since you are using `await` in there as well.